# On onLongPressGresture navigate to another SwiftUI screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 3 Text in SwiftUI (in UIKit UILabel) , I need to navigate to other screen when I use onLongPressGresture in one of my Text, below is the code.

Parent View Controller which is UIKit and has tableView
when user will click on specific row I am showing swiftUI screen which is Class A

Parent class to Class A navigation code is

```
let classA = ClassA()
let navigateToClassA = UIHostingController(rootView: classA)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigateToClassA, animated: true)
```

Now I am landing to Class A and below is Class A code

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 7) {
         Text("user 1")
         Text("Long Press Here")
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2) {
             (I need to add navigation code here so I will navigate to other SwiftUI screen)  
       }
       Text("User 2")
 }
 .navigationTitle("Class A")
}
```

this is my Class B code which will show when I will navigate from onLongPressGesture in Class A

```
struct classB: View {

var body: some View {
VStack(alignment: .leading){
     Text("Hello")
  }
  .navigationTitle("Class B")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var isChildViewPresented: Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 7) {
                    Text("user 1")
                    Text("Long Press Here")
                        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2) {
                            isChildViewPresented = true
                        }
                    Text("User 2")
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isChildViewPresented) {
                    Text("ChildView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically you need to wrap everything inside e `NavigationStack`, i would personally prefer it over the `NavigationView` since the latter one is going to be obsolete.
You make use of the state variable `isChildViewPresented`, and change its state when you want to perform the navigation.
By making use of the `.navigationDestination` you specify it where to navigate to when the state of the `isChildViewPresented` is toggled

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help, its working as expected, the only issue I am facing is its showing two NavigationBars when I am landing to another SwiftUI view.

Comment: Most probably you already are inside a NavigationView or a NavigationStack, could you provide me with more context of your code? Because for me it's working just fine

Comment: More code context added

Comment: As i was expecting, you already are inside a NavigationController, try to replace this: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigateToClassA, animated: true) with  something like this
addChild(navigateToClassA)
view.addSubview(navigateToClassA.view)
navigateToClassA.didMove(toParent: self)

Comment: I tried these your last suggestions its still showing Nav, I believe because my parent class is one of the tabBar item and that's why I am already in navigationView or Stack, is there any other way to handle navigation in swiftUI ?